# Git: Is there a safe way to delete a branch, including all commits/history from it to restore original repo size

Tags: git, branch

I have a request from someone to use Git to transfer a large binary file as a one-time work around (to transfer files between 2 people).  He is having some network issues preventing him from using standard tools (like Dropbox, GDrive, Ftp, etc), but has full connectivity to my Git repo.

My biggest concern with permitting him to do this is that it will increase the size of my repo.  Even if he creates a new branch, makes a commit with the binary file, and deletes the branch once successfully pulled by the other party, will the repo not retain the history associated with that commit?

If the file is fairly large (100M), will my repo not grow by that amount even if the branch is deleted?  What would I need to do to re-shrink the repo back to the pre-commit size?

Comment: I don’t think so; in my quick experiment even `git gc --prune=all --aggressive` doesn’t work, and the `git` manpages recommend against using `--prune=all` because it isn’t safe in some cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once *all* references to some commit(s) and their associated file(s)—really, underlying Git objects (the trees and blobs that go with those commits)—are gone, the objects become *eligible* for garbage collection.  They will, however, not actually *be* collected until something runs `git gc` (or `git prune`) *and* they are at least as old as the "prune time".

The default prune time is two weeks, but you may lower it with, e.g., `git gc --prune=yesterday` or `--prune=10.minutes.ago` or similar.  If you make this time very small, be sure that no one is creating new objects within the repository.

Getting rid of *all* references to various Git objects can be harder than it looks.  The obvious ones are branch names and tag names.  These reference names usually also have *reflogs*, and there is an additional reflog for `HEAD` itself; all these reflogs contains references, which then keep the objects alive.  Deleting the branch name (currently) deletes the branch's reflog but those in `HEAD`'s reflog remain.

The reflog entries themselves expire, by default, in 90 days for *reachable* objects and 30 days for *unreachable* ones, with this reachability determined by the current value of the corresponding reference.  If the only reference to a commit is in the `HEAD` reflog and `HEAD` is not itself detached, that reflog reference points to an unreachable commit (by definition: if `HEAD` is attached to a branch, then `HEAD` contains only a branch name, and we already said that no branch name points to the commit itself, nor to a descendant of the commit), so only the shorter expiry applies.  You can shorten it further with `git reflog expire --expire-unreachable=...`, using the same syntax as with `git gc --prune=...`, though of course you will be expiring *all* such unreachable reflog entries unless you restrict this to `HEAD` (then you will cull only `HEAD`'s unreachable entries).

Besides these, it's possible to have a reference in one of the special `*_HEAD` names (`ORIG_HEAD`, `MERGE_HEAD`, `CHERRY_PICK_HEAD`, and so on).  That's not likely for this particular case, though.